# tableview header logo like iBooks App

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiview, uiimage

How can I insert an image in the header of a tableView so that it stays has the iBook App?
When you scroll down, Apple's logo appears, and when you let go, is disappear?

Is works, I guess, just like a view in the table's header, but if that's so, how to create that condition to hide like the iBooks App does?

Thanks,

RL

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The iBook app doesn't use a `UITableView` (my guess), but a `UIScrollView`.

A `UITableView` **isA** `UIScrollView` however.

And I don't think what you're asking about is really a "header".  It's hidden content above the content of the scroll view.

A scroll view had a `contentSize` rectangle, (which is usually bigger that its `bounds`), and a `contentOffset` point (in which only the `y` value is offset in a table view).

You want to add a child view to the scroll/table view with it's `frame` set to have a negative `y` value (likely the equivalent of its `height`).

Comment: view.frame = CGRectMake(0,-100,320,100); [tableView addSubview:view];

Comment: if you want to convince yourself it's there: view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];